# tail inequality for expectations

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, integral-inequality

I would like to upper bound the expectation 
$$
\mathbb{E}[X \, \textbf{1}\{X > t\}],
$$
where $\textbf{I}\{p\}$ evaluates to $1$ if $p$ is true, $0$ otherwise, and $X$ is some non-negative random variable which may be assumed to be sub-Gaussian.

The discrete case is easy, but I'm having trouble with the continuous case. Is anyone familiar with existing results or useful inequalities for this?

edit: assume also that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu < \infty$

Comment: 1. If $E(X)$ is infinite, then $E(X\mathbf 1\{X\gt t\})=+\infty$ for every $t$. 2. For every nonincreasing function $\varepsilon$ with limit zero, one can find some random variable $X$ with $E(X)$ finite such that $E(X\mathbf 1\{X\gt t\})\geqslant\varepsilon(t)$ for every $t$.

Comment: thanks, I added an assumption w.r.t (1). I'm unsure how to use (2) it's not quite a counter example.

Comment: Why not? $ $ $ $

Comment: I've assumed $X$ is sub-Gaussian primarily, it's quite clear that a sharp upper bound exists for simple examples, bounded $X$ for example.

Comment: Did you read my comment? 'Cause, you see, what you mention is quite unrelated to it.

Comment: So there always exists a random variable which is difficult to bound in some sense. I don't see how to use this. In any event, one is going to choose a $t$ that leads to non vacuous upper bounds, $t > \mathbb{E}[X]$ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious estimate $\mathbb E[X \; 1\{X>t\}] \le \mathbb E[X]$
is best-possible in the sense that it is an equality if $\mathbb P(0 < X < t) = 0$.

Somewhat more generally, if $\mathbb E[X^p] < \infty$ with $p \ge 1$ you have
$$\mathbb E[X \; 1\{X > t\}] \le t^{1-p} \mathbb E[X^p]$$

EDIT: And, if the moment generating function $M(s) = \mathbb E[e^{sX}] < \infty$ for some $s > 0$, this implies
$$\mathbb E[X \; 1\{X > t\}] \le \dfrac{t}{e^{st}-1} (M(s) - 1)$$
so this gives you exponential decay.

Comment: ah interesting, sub-Gaussian RV do have bounded (absolute) moments, do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: It's just a pointwise bound: $x \; 1\{x > t\} \le t^{1-p} x^p$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Comment: ah, yes, thanks!

Comment: actually, how did you recover the last inequality. If X is SG we have $M(s) = \mathbb{E}[e^{sX}] \leq \exp\{b^2s^2/2\}$ for some $b > 0$, plugging this into the last inequality and letting $s = 2t/b^2$ we get $\mathbb{E}[X 1\{X > t\}] \leq \frac{t}{\exp\{2t^2/b^2\} - 1}(\exp\{2t^2/b^2\} - 1) = t$, which cannot be right

Comment: Actually it's not right.  Remember you assumed $X$ is non-negative. 
Sub-Gaussian random variables must have $E[X] = 0$.  So (except for the trivial case $X=0$ a.s.) you can't have both non-negative and sub-Gaussian.